# What is the best place to enable gzip compression on an application running with proxy

Tags: nginx, gzip, wildfly-8, http-compression

My application is running on WildFly application server with NGINX proxy server on front. I have enabled gzip on WildFly and everything working fine when I access WildFly directly. But when I accessed via proxy there is content-encoding: gzip header in response. So I added gzip configuration in nginx and it worked. So what is the best method to enable gzip when you application is fronted with proxy server?

Comment: AFAIK the best approach is to gzip it on backend, then Nginx will not double-zip it and serve compressed response to the client.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I can't see content-encoding: gzip header in response. When I configure gzip in nginx, header is present in response.

Comment: just add a header: *add_header Content-Encoding $upstream_http_content_encoding;*

Comment: I have removed gzip enabling in proxy and just added this header but there is no change in response. When I hard code "gzip" instead of $upstream_http_content_encoding, it's showing error for resources that are not gzipped. That means control reaches here but due to some reason it's not setting $upstream_http_content_encoding in response header.